# How to apply SVG clipPath with CSS to one edge of div?

Tags: css, svg, clip-path

I have a layout with a number of different curves to apply to the top and/or bottom of full-width boxes. I'm almost there, using an SVG `clipPath` element with `clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"`, applied to the box using CSS `clip-path: url(#curve)`. However, currently the curve scales proportionally, and I'd like it to maintain its height as the width scales with the box.

Here is my current code:

```css
.box {

  height: 100vw;
  background-color: red;
  clip-path: url(#curve);

}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>

<svg>
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="curve" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
            <path d="M0 0.00880688C0 0.00880688 0.101517 -0.0152445 0.276014 0.0161458C0.474915 0.0519263 0.605365 0.0594333 0.727565 0.0493416C0.83584 0.0403992 1 0.0124763 1 0.0124763V1H0V0.00880688Z"/>
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

I think the problem is that using `clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"` means that while the curve always starts at the left edge of the box, and finishes at the right edge (as desired), the height of it changes in relation to the box's height. I've set the height here to `100vw` to (just about) see this in action. What I need to for the path to behave as it currently does left-to-right (always fit the box), but top-to-bottom I want the same height covered by the curve path, whatever the box height. I sense I need something like `clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"` for the X axis but `clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse"` for Y. I don't think that's possible, but I'm stuck for another way to approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it as mask and define its width to be `100%` and an `auto` height

```css
.box {
  height: 200px; /* this can be any height and it won't affect the curvature */
  -webkit-mask:
    url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1 1"><path d="M0 0.00880688C0 0.00880688 0.101517 -0.0152445 0.276014 0.0161458C0.474915 0.0519263 0.605365 0.0594333 0.727565 0.0493416C0.83584 0.0403992 1 0.0124763 1 0.0124763V1H0V0.00880688Z" fill="black"/></svg>') 
    top/100% auto no-repeat;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

You can also consider a fixed height but you need to use `preserveAspectRatio="none"`

```css
.box {
  height: 200px; /* this can be any height and it won't affect the curvature */
  -webkit-mask:
    url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg preserveAspectRatio="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1 1"><path d="M0 0.00880688C0 0.00880688 0.101517 -0.0152445 0.276014 0.0161458C0.474915 0.0519263 0.605365 0.0594333 0.727565 0.0493416C0.83584 0.0403992 1 0.0124763 1 0.0124763V1H0V0.00880688Z" fill="black"/></svg>') 
    top/100% 1000px no-repeat;
    /*        ^--- adjust this like you want (at least bigger than the height) */
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Excellent, many thanks - for some reason CSS masks had passed me by. They seem much more suited to this use case.

Comment: One note: using this method almost got there, but when the box was tall and narrow, the bottom of the mask shape was cutting off the contents at the bottom of the box. I solved this by putting a `:before` pseudo-element into the box, and applying a mask to it (with the shape being just the curve with a minimal height). Keep the proportion of the pseudo-element with some padding-top, and it worked well.

Comment: @SteveTaylor you can also consider an extra mask layer to cover the bottom part like below: https://jsfiddle.net/9pzg1cbd/ (you simply need to find the best value [the `10vw` I have used in the example] to make sure there is no gap with the top later)